# Which statistics method to use test reclassification?

Tags: classification

If we have a traditional method of classifying a disease which has some indeterminate patients and a new method for which those indeterminate patients were classified to either high or low risk groups, which statistical method can we use to show that there’s benefit to using the new model for classifying these groups? We thought about NRI/IDI, but not really sure if this will work in our case since there’re only a few indeterminate.